# Lobibox: Close previous notification

Tags: jquery, lobibox

Anyone know how, using the Lobibox (http://lobianijs.com/site/lobibox), to close the previous notification when showing a new one? I have this example:

```
Lobibox.notify(
    'info', {
        title: 'Duplicating line',
        msg  : 'Wait...',
        size : 'mini',
        delay: false
    }
);

$.ajax({
    type    : 'GET',
    url     : $url + '_save.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data    : {
        "action"        : "duplicate",
        "ide": ide,
        "idf": idf
    },
    success : function () {
        Lobibox.notify(
            'success', {
                title: 'Duplicating line',
                msg  : 'Done!',
                size : 'mini'
            }
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure `Lobibox` supports this by default, but I found `remove` event inside instance of it.

So you can get the instance and call `notification1.remove();` this will remove the one which you are trying to.

pretty hard to find out cdn of it :D

**Example:**

```js
var notification1 = Lobibox.notify(
  'info', {
    title: 'Duplicating line1',
    msg: 'Wait...',
    size: 'mini',
    delay: false
  }
);

setTimeout(() => {
  notification1.remove();
  var notification2 = Lobibox.notify(
    'info', {
      title: 'Duplicating line2',
      msg: 'Wait...',
      size: 'mini',
      delay: false
    }
  );

}, 400);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lobibox@1.2.7/dist/css/lobibox.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lobibox@1.2.7/lib/jquery.1.11.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lobibox@1.2.7/dist/js/lobibox.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```